# Scala dynamic field named x

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

Just implementing a Dynamic object (using 2.10.0-M3):

```
import language.dynamics
object D extends Dynamic {
    def selectDynamic( field : String ) = Symbol( field )
}
```

The following works fine and as expected

```
object DynamicTest extends App {
    println( D.a )
}
```

Printing 'a

But, if I try this:

```
object DynamicTest extends App {
    println( D.x )
}
```

I get nasty errors:

```
[error] DynProb.scala:7: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : D.type
[error]  required: ?{val x: ?}
[error] Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
[error]  both method any2Ensuring in object Predef of type [A](x: A)Ensuring[A]
[error]  and method any2ArrowAssoc in object Predef of type [A](x: A)ArrowAssoc[A]
[error]  are possible conversion functions from D.type to ?{val x: ?}
[error]     println( D.x )
[error]              ^
[error] one error found
```

Why is x so special?  I am doing something stupid?

Comment: That’s the problem: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L271

Comment: So, I essentially have to live with it until the thing is actually removed from the lib, not just deprecated.  Shame.  Thanks for the pointer :-)

Comment: Here's a thought: assuming that Dynamic first tries to find a suitable name in scope before trying selectDynamic, etc. Should it avoid deprecated names, too?

Comment: That sounds more like a question for a Scala developer’s mailing list. But maybe someone else can enlighten the SO readers with more insight on Scala’s order of resolution.

Comment: @hughleat The deprecation cycle exists to avoid breaking code that depends on what's being deprecated. If the resolution order as different, code would break. Alas, I think it's well worth bringing this particular case up and asking that the normal deprecation cycle be shortened, as it's extremely unlikely for people to be using `x` intentionally this way.

Comment: @Debilski whatever you were pointing at with that link seems to have moved. It's now pointing into the middle of StringAdd.

Comment: @johnsullivan The block with `final class ArrowAssoc[A](val __leftOfArrow: A) extends AnyVal` or https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/399ab16c296021de8fff1f0dd234f5f21230e82e/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L271 (for 2.10.0-M3).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a simple solution for now:

```
import language.dynamics
object D extends Dynamic {
    def selectDynamic( field : String ) = Symbol( field )
    def x = selectDynamic("x")
}
D.x
```

Returns the expected

```
res2: Symbol = 'x
```

I would have loved to redefine a trait named `CompleteDynamic` to do this "x" variable overriding but I could not for the moment.